# Map values in column with a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two dataframes imported from files

df1 output(sample):

| Country | Currency | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNITED STATES | US DOLLAR | USD |
| PUERTO RICO | US DOLLAR | USD |
| UNITED KINGDOM | UK POUND STERLING | GBP |
| GUERNSEY | UK POUND STERLING | GBP |
| JAPAN | JAPANESE YEN | JPY |

df2 output(sample):

| index | Original Currency |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | US DOLLAR |
| 1 | UK POUND STERLING |
| 2 | JAPANESE YEN |
| 3 | US DOLLAR |
| 4 | US DOLLAR |
| 5 | UK POUND STERLING |

I have converted both columns from df1 to a dictionary using:
`di = dict(zip(df1['Currency'], df1['Code']))`

Currently, I am trying to map the values from my dictionary to my second dataframe's 'Original Currency' column; however, the attempts I have made either result in NaN values or no change at all.

I have attempted using both `.map()` and `.replace()` with little success

With `.map()`

```
df2['Original Currency'] = df2['Original Currency'].map(di)
```

With `.replace()`

```
df2['Original Currency'] = df2['Original Currency'].replace(di)

&

df3 = df2.replace({"Original Currency": di})
```

Comment: I've added additional data to both dataframes. It was a mistake on my part to not include this originally as the repeat values prevent me from using any of the solutions provided previously.

Comment: So do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. Try this:

```
df2['Original Currency'] = df2['Original Currency'].map(df1.set_index('Currency')['Code'])
print(df2)

# Output
  Original Currency
0               USD
1               GBP
2               JPY
```

If it doesn't work, maybe you have some trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to reply sooner. I was able to use the code you suppled and found a solution. The whitespace was an issue so I used the .str.stip() function. Also, dropped duplicate 'Currency' values from df1 as I realized for the mapping to work, my index had to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply

```
df2['Original Currency'] = df2['Original Currency'].apply(lambda i: di[i])
```